# Drawer Navigation and Bottom Navigation in same activity Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, androidx

I'm using SDK 28 and android X element.
I'm trying imitate Instagram's UI 
I had already try to combine two deafult navigation from Android Studio template. 
And it has some coulples bug that I can't fix. 
I'm coding Navigation on MainActivity.kt

Take example like : 
1.Missing the Humbuger Icon at Fragment what launch by Bottom Navigation 
2.Drawer Navigation Didn't Cover Navigation

### Code

Main Activity

```
package com.odstudio.ourdiet

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.navigateUp
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow, R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send
            ), drawerLayout
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
        val bottomNavView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation)
        bottomNavView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)

    }

  //  override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    //    Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
      //  menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
        //return true
   // }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }

    private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener =
        BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
            when (item.itemId) {
                R.id.navigation_home -> {
                    findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.nav_home)
                }
                R.id.navigation_groups -> {
                    findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.nav_groups)
                }
                R.id.navigation_friends -> {
                    findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.nav_friends)
                }
            }
            false
        }
}
```

### Layout

Activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_bottom" />

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-200dp"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

app_bar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

### Image

[Home Page WithoutHumbuger Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SfLr.png) 
[Drawer Navigation Didn't Cover Navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrDI2.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, this one was pretty straight forward. I took the default nav drawer project and added a few changes.

First, wrap the DrawerLayout and your added BottomNavigation in a ConstraintLayout.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Then in MainActivy add the OnNavigationSelectedListener and set it in onCreate()

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,
                R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send
            ), drawerLayout
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }

    private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when (item.itemId) {
             // Set up navigation here
when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.navigation_rivers -> findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.nav_river)
        }   R.id.navigation_favorites -> findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.nav_favs)
            R.id.navigation_map -> findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.nav_map)
        }
        false
    }
```

And make sure you have your bottom nav menu setup.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_rivers"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_sea"
            android:title="@string/title_rivers"/>

    <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_favorites"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_heart"
            android:title="@string/title_favorites"/>

    <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_map"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_location"
            android:title="@string/title_map"/>
</menu>
```

**UPDATE:** 
I updated MainActivity.kt above.

Here is my nav graph mobile_navigation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/nav_home">

   <!-- Other Drawer Fragments here, removed for brevity -->

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_share"
        android:name="com.stackoverflowdualnav.ui.share.ShareFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_share"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_share" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_send"
        android:name="com.stackoverflowdualnav.ui.send.SendFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_send"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_send" />

    <!-- Bottom Nav Below -->

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_river"
        android:name="com.stackoverflowdualnav.ui.send.RiverFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_river"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_river" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_favs"
        android:name="com.stackoverflowdualnav.ui.send.FavoritesFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_favorites"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_map" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_map"
        android:name="com.stackoverflowdualnav.ui.send.NavMapFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_map"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_map" />
```

This works as-is, just adapt it to your use case.

Comment: So i have to put all fragment in same mobile_navigation (the navigation graph)

Comment: Yeah, that is what I did. But you could do it however that fits your needs, here I will add some more code, just pelase don't forget to accept this as the answer if it helps.

Comment: Can I ask you some questions on Twitter ( Cause I need send Couple pics ) I had already tag you at Twitter~

Comment: Work Perfect with using  findNavController